# a number of things

Tags: grammatical-number

I think that "a number of things" literally means "a number", with no implication regarding how many.

However, a friend of mine argues that "a number of things" means "The majority of things."

For example, supposing there are 100 students in a class, "a number of students in the class," according to my friend, refers to more than 50 students.

I'd like to know what do you think about this, as native speakers. Thank you!

Comment: You need better friends to practice English with.

Comment: You're right, your friend is wrong.

Comment: "A number of friends" idiomatically means "several friends", not just an integer. Typically, it would refer to more than one friend, but not necessarily a majority of the group.

Comment: "Number" is a somewhat imprecise quantificational noun. It typically denotes a quantity somewhere between a few and a lot.

Comment: I'm sure a number of people agree with your friend.  I don't.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The general meaning of *a number of* is ***several***.

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+number+of):

> **a number of**
>
> A collection of persons or things; *several*.
>
> For example, A number of tours are available, or We've visited a number of
> times.

[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/number):

> **number**
>
> 2.1 (**a number of**) *Several*: we have discussed the matter on a number of occasions
>
> More example sentences:
>
> The company has ruled out on a number
> of occasions a full listing on the stock market.
>
> It has been
> reiterated on several occasions since through a number of declarations
> and statements.
>
> All credit to Liverpool who put up a great fight and
> could have scored through Owen on a number of occasions.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/number):

> **number**
>
> 6. a certain collection, company, or quantity *not* precisely reckoned, but usually considerable or large: I've gone there a number of times.